# How do I use \newcommand to print a matrix everytime I input 6 values?

Tags: macros

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I still don't really know how to use the `\newcommand` feature at all (new to stackexchange as well). I've been trying to find out how to print something like this
[image: cross product matrix]

I've tried various ways and so far the code with the least number of errors is this:

```
\newcommand{\xmatrix}[6]{
\begin{vmatrix}
    $i & j & k$\\
    {u1} & {u2} & {u3}\\
    {v1} & {v2} & {v3}
\end{vmatrix}}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just using the `\newcommand` part wrong but I want to be able to print the unit vectors in bold in the first row and the next 6 numbers are input. Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define a macro with six arguments: those six arguments are represented by `#1`, ..., `#6` in the macro code. Since `vmatrix` is always in math mode there is no need to use `$` dollar signs within it. You could therefore do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for vmatrix

\newcommand{\xmatrix}[6]{%
\begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    #1 & #2 & #3\\
    #4 & #5 & #6
\end{vmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\[
\xmatrix{u1}{u2}{u3}{v1}{v2}{v3}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, I find a macro taking six arguments a little bit unpleasant and prone to errors. I propose an alternative definition with *two* arguments, each of them being a comma-separated list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\xmatrix}[2]{{%
   \def\@xmatrix##1,##2,##3,##4\relax{##1 & ##2 & ##3}%
   \begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    \@xmatrix#1,,,\relax\\
    \@xmatrix#2,,,\relax
   \end{vmatrix}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\xmatrix{u1,u2,u3}{v1,v2,v3}
\quad
\xmatrix{u1}{,v2,v3} % just as example
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a bit confused as to what the \makeatletter and \makeatother do. Also what does the % and the @ do in this case?

Comment: @msun5040 See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/82917) and [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/82917). The `%` are not really necessary here (spaces are ignored in math mode) but they are an habit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do much better than defining a macro with six arguments. I propose just two arguments, representing the coefficients of the vectors as comma separated lists.

We can also define a variant that actually *computes* the cross product.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\crossproduct}{s m m}
 {% #1 = optional *
  % #2 = first vector as comma list
  % #3 = second vector as comma list
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% *-variant, compute the product
    \msun_crossproduct_compute:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {% normal, typeset in determinant form
    \msun_crossproduct_symbolic:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\fp_new:N \l_msun_crossproduct_i_fp
\fp_new:N \l_msun_crossproduct_j_fp
\fp_new:N \l_msun_crossproduct_k_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \msun_crossproduct_compute:nn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l_msun_crossproduct_i_fp
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 3 }
    -
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 2 }
   }
  \fp_set:Nn \l_msun_crossproduct_j_fp
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 }
    -
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 3 }
   }
  \fp_set:Nn \l_msun_crossproduct_k_fp
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 2 }
    -
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 } * \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 }
   }
  \fp_use:N \l_msun_crossproduct_i_fp \mathbf{i}
  \fp_compare:nF { \l_msun_crossproduct_j_fp < \c_zero_fp } { + }
  \fp_use:N \l_msun_crossproduct_j_fp \mathbf{j}
  \fp_compare:nF { \l_msun_crossproduct_k_fp < \c_zero_fp } { + }
  \fp_use:N \l_msun_crossproduct_k_fp \mathbf{k}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \msun_crossproduct_symbolic:nn
 {
  \begin{vmatrix}
  \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}
  \\
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 } & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 }
  \\
  \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } & \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 2 } & \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 3 }
  \end{vmatrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\crossproduct{0,1,-2}{3,0,-4}=
\crossproduct*{0,1,-2}{3,0,-4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]